# SQL How do I find duplicates from a combination of 2 columns case and accent insensitive

Tags: sql, sql-server

A table has information from 2 input streams where users might appear in both, however with slight variations. I'm trying to find these duplicate users. I've come up with this SQL statement which finds most of these users:

```
SELECT s.PROF_MAIL, s.PROF_STATE, s.PROF_GUID, CONCAT(s.PROF_GIVEN_NAME,' ',s.PROF_SURNAME) AS FullName, t.*
FROM [EMPLOYEE] s
join (
    SELECT PROF_GIVEN_NAME,PROF_SURNAME, count(*) as qty
      FROM [EMPLOYEE] 
      GROUP BY PROF_GIVEN_NAME,PROF_SURNAME 
      HAVING count(*) > 1
    ) t on s.PROF_GIVEN_NAME = t.PROF_GIVEN_NAME AND s.PROF_SURNAME = t.PROF_SURNAME
```

The problem is that names can have an accent like René in one source and not in the other. Also the capitals are not necessarily the same. These are not captured in above statement. I therefore tried to incorporate COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI somewhere, but couldn't figure out where to use this or how to solve this in another way. Anybody knows how to do this? Database is MS SQL

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: D-Shih, for some background, this is a table from IBM Connections. The relevant part of the data is that the displayname has initials in one and not the other, so is unusable. The concatenation of given name and surname however doesn't have the initials, which makes it usable. The problem is that with this concatenation you might have names like 'René de Jong' and 'Rene De Jong' which should be matched, but aren't in above sql statement

Answer (score 0):

First, you should use window functions:

```
select e.*
from (select e.*,
             count(*) over (partition by prof_given_name, prof_surname) as cnt
      from employees e
     ) e
where cnt > 1;
```

You can now incorporate the `collate` in the `partition by` clause:

```
select e.*
from (select e.*,
             count(*) over (partition by prof_given_name collate Latin1_General_CI_AI, prof_surname collate Latin1_General_CI_AI) as cnt
      from employees e
     ) e
where cnt > 1;
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked and caught about 500 (=7%) extra records, so it was worth the effort

Answer (score 0):

You could use [ROW_NUMBER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/ranking-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) window function with the names in the PARTITION BY like so (incorporate COLLATE too)

```
;WITH cteDups
AS(
    SELECT
        *,RN=ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY 
                                  PROF_GIVEN_NAME COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI, 
                                  PROF_SURNAME COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI 
                        ORDER BY PROF_SURNAME ASC )
    FROM    dbo.Employee
)
SELECT * FROM cteDups WHERE cteDups.RN > 1
```

If the `EMPLOYEE` table has a `DATETIME` column that records when the row was created then replace the `ORDER BY` with that column so that you can identify the most recent record